# After initial connection service UUID shows up fine however subsequent connections fail to see the service UUID

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, esp32

On Android, after initial connection service UUID shows up fine however subsequent connections fail to see the service UUID.

When the device is bound and paired service UUID on discovery shows up correctly.

When the device is bound and unpaired and then repaired the service UUID on discovery shows generic UUID's
`00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`
`00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`

This occurs on Android 11 & 12, not tested on 10.

Comment: Please try to use a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to scan your BLE device. Does this behavior happen as well?

Comment: Yes it does. We tried nRF Connect as well as LightBlue

Comment: This could be a problem with your BLE peripheral. Could you [edit] your question and add more information about it or some source code?